# How can I make this function run in order? I may be misunderstanding async, await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a function that handles the addition of some data into my database. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I believe this is because the `eDataBuilder` function is taking too long to complete the loop, thus making the validation inside `sendQuery` return false.

I did try to use async/await, but I think maybe I'm misunderstanding how it's supposed to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Event Handler**

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sData = this.state;
    var iType = this.state.itemType;
    var eData = {};
    var changeItem = this.changeItemType;

    async function eDataBuilder() {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sData)) {
      if(sData[`${key}`] !== '') {
        eData[`${key}`] = `${value}`;
      }
    }
    await sendQuery();
  }
  function sendQuery() {
    if (Object.keys(eData).length > 2) {
      API.addItem(eData)
         .then(response => {
           if (response === 'ok') {
           let event = {target: {value: iType}};
           changeItem(event);
           alert('Item added successfully.');
         } else {
           alert('There was an error while attempting to add your item. Please try again.');
         }
         });
    } else {
      alert('Must enter at least some data.');
    }
  }
  eDataBuilder();
  }
```

**API FUNCTION**

```
addItem: function(iData) {
    return axios.post('/addItem', iData)
                .then(response => (response.data === 'ok') ? 'ok' : 'no')
                .catch(error => console.log('Error: ' + error));
  }
```

**Express/Sequelize function**

```
app.post('/addItem', function(request, response) {
    db.Item.create(request.body)
    .then((data) => {
      response.send('ok');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
    });
  });
```

Comment: since `sendQuery` isn't called until the for loop ends, the for loop isn't "taking too long" - it is done before the call to the function

Comment: your main issue is that in the case of response not 'ok' ... you should check why

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok, I think I understand. I went ahead and added the api function and back end express/sequelize query. If you have a moment to take a look I'd appreciate it. In the meantime I'll keep what you said in mind and see if I can't figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: @JaromandaX It seems like `Object.keys(eData).length > 2` is returning as false. That may be my issue because when it fails I'm getting the `alert('Must enter at least some data.');` to run. In that object I should have two key/value pairs by default, so the length should be 2, then after I take an action to add a third it still returns false. (at least the first time after I reset everything.

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey, sorry for sending so many messages. I think I figured it out. There is a piece of data that is added to the object when the component loads. Since I can't use the function prior to logging in, the data is unavailable, thus it can't be defined and my object's length is -1. I didn't provide enough information on this question to answer it completely, but I didn't know at the time I made it. Thank you for the help, your tip pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use async await for this use case. Simply change your code and write without async await.

Simply try this.

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var sData = this.state;
var iType = this.state.itemType;
var eData = {};
var changeItem = this.changeItemType;


for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sData)) {
    if (sData[`${key}`] !== '') {
        eData[`${key}`] = `${value}`;
    }
}
function sendQuery() {
    if (Object.keys(eData).length > 2) {
        API.addItem(eData)
            .then(response => {
                if (response === 'ok') {
                    let event = { target: { value: iType } };
                    changeItem(event);
                    alert('Item added successfully.');
                } else {
                    alert('There was an error while attempting to add your item. Please try again.');
                }
            });
    } else {
        alert('Must enter at least some data.');
    }
}
sendQuery();
```

}